# alignat at 3 columns

Tags: align, alignat

```tex
\newcommand{\update}{\leftarrow}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c - 1] &\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c + 1] &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c + 1] &\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c - 1] &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c] &\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c] &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
\end{alignat*}
```

What I have currently:
[image]

Can I change it so that the second \wedge is aligned with the others as well?

Basically I want three alignments:

- Left-alignment
- Alignment in the middle \wedge
- Alignment at the \to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot that n alignment points require 2n-1 ampersands, as  except for the first column, each new alignment point requires one `&` to mark the beginning of a new column, and another `&` to mark the alignment point inside this column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\newcommand{\update}{\leftarrow}

\begin{document}

\begin{alignat*}{3}
c &= 0 \wedge [c \update c - 1] & & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c + 1] & &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
c &= 0 \wedge [c \update c + 1] & & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c - 1] & &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
c &= 0 \wedge [c \update c] & & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c] & &\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Can use `array` as well.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\update}{\leftarrow}
\[
\begin{array}{l@{\;}l@{\;}l}
c = 0 \wedge [c \update c - 1] & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c + 1] & \to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
c = 0 \wedge [c \update c + 1] & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c - 1] & \to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
c = 0 \wedge [c \update c]     & \wedge \bigcirc [c \update c]     & \to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an `alignat` environment, you need to tell it to use `3` columns (that is, three pairs of one right-aligned and one left-aligned column). And you need to place the alignment markers accordingly.

Because you do not want the first column to be right-aligned, you need to place the first alignment marker at the start of each line to leave the first (right-aligned) column empty.

The next columns should also not be right-aligned, so you need to place two ampersands before the `\wedge` symbol and the `\to` symbol. This way, all the right-aligned columns will be empty and what is left is three left-aligned columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\update}{\leftarrow}
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c - 1] &&\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c + 1] &&\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c + 1] &&\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c - 1] &&\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
&c = 0 \wedge [c \update c] &&\wedge \bigcirc [c \update c] &&\to \bigcirc \bigcirc c = 0 \\
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused -- wouldn't this be 4 columns?

Comment: Well, 2 columns essentially means 2 pairs of one right-aligned and one left-align column. So you would have `right-aligned & left-aligned & right-aligned & left-aligned`. But here, we need more in order to have everything aligned properly.

Comment: Your code has a small problem:  normally, 3 columns require 5 &. Here it works because the final part is the same in all equations.

Comment: Yes, this is true. Thanks for pointing this out.